# How to return OUT parameters from stored procedure in Symfony 1.4 using Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm not sure how to properly retrieve the OUT parameters from a stored procedure in symfony using doctrine.

My stored procedure looks like:

```
PROCEDURE procedure_name (IN val1 NUMERIC(10), ... , OUT out1 NUMERIC(10), OUT out2 NUMERIC(10), OUT out3 NUMERIC(10))
```

I've tried:

```
$sql = "CALL procedure_name('$val1', ... , @out1, @out2, @out3)";
$con = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
$statement = $con->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result = $con->query("SELECT @out1, @out2, @out3")->fetch_object();
```

But that fails with the error "You must have at least one component specified in your from."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
$sql = "CALL procedure_name('$val1', ... , @out1, @out2, @out3)";
$con = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$statement = $con->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();
$result = $con->fetchAssoc("SELECT @out1, @out2, @out3");
```